# Partial specialization and const conundrum in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, partial-specialization

A class template:

`template <class X, class Y > class MyTemplate;`

I want to partially specialize this class so that when X is a const type, Y is an `int` and that partial specialization code is chosen if I create an object such as:

`MyTemplate<sometype const> var;`

whereas if X is a non-const type, Y is a `double` and that partial specialization code is chosen if I create an object such as:

`MyTemplate<sometype> var;`

Is this possible in C++11 ? If so, how ? If not, is this possible in C++20 with concepts and requirements ?

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use partial specialization for this?

Comment: If you will not give a second type argument, you ought to use a different template name rather than a partial specialization of the first.  The specialization is good only if you just want that different default for Y but the user could still specify any type for Y.

Comment: Do you need the Y parameter? Or is it fixed from `X`?

Answer (score 2):

Partial specialization (with possibly enabler):

```
template <class X, class Y, typename Enabler = void> class MyTemplate;

template <class X>
class MyTemplate<const X, int>
{
// ...
};

template <class X>
class MyTemplate<X, double, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<X>>>
{
// ...
};

//...
```

Replace the C++14 `X_t<T>`/`X_v<T>` by `typename X<T>::type`/`X<T>::value` to be C++11.

Comment: Thank you ! I was trying to avoid using an extra parameter with enable_if, but your solution is certainly valid.

Comment: But it seems, I misread the question, if you want to fix `Y` from `X` property.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use partial specialization for this. You can just write:

```
template <typename X, 
          typename Y = 
          typename std::conditional<std::is_const<X>::value, int, double>::type> 
class MyTemplate;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z51o7e)

Comment: I still need partial specialization to handle the two code cases of X being a const type or not, but I worked out how to do that. My previous effort only specified X in each partial specialization but when I realized I needed to specify both X and Y in each partial specialization, and not just X, I got everything working correctly.

Comment: Maybe `template <typename X> class MyTemplate { using Y = double; /*..*/ };` and specialization `template <typename X> class MyTemplate<const X> { using Y = int; /*..*/ };` is what you want then.

Comment: The actual situation is much more complicated than just fixing Y from X based on whether X is const or not. I just presented it in that form to understand how I would implement the basics of having two basic diffferent situations for partial specialization, one in which X is non-const and one in which it is const.